# iboutlet in document based application

Tags: xcode, document, iboutlet

i am searching from over 2 hours without finding an answer!

i am a noob in xcode and cocoa programming.. basically my xib file contains a tab view, and in one of the tabs i placed a webview. i also added the web framework.

my app is a document based application. and i am not able to declare an iboutlet for the webview in order to make it load a URL.

how am i supposed to declare the iboutlet in a document based application? and evne more in what file am i supposed to do it?

please keep the answer as simple as possible since i am veeery green in this and coming from Windows it takes some time understand the mac environment.

tahnk you!

Igor

Comment: It's not clear why having an outlet in a document based application would be any different from having an outlet in any other application. Can you create the outlet you want in a non-document based application? If so, can you explain what's confusing you about doing the same thing in your document based application?

Comment: it gets a red exclamation mark! i get the message "unknown type name 'WebView'" so i think that i made something wrong.. all i want to do is load a default URL in the webview when the program loads.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "WebView", so that's probably why you're getting that error. Do you mean "NSWebView"?

Comment: if i type that then i get an error message, "id you mean WebView".. problem was i had to implement the webkit. so now i dont have errors but it does not work anyway. i am unable to load a url when the app loads..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probelm solved!

first i fogto to implement the webkit framework, then i added the implementation to the app delegate instead of the document. thus when opening a document it did not load the page!

thanks for your help anyway jemmons!

Answer (score 1):

I think : you have to import WebKit:

## import < WebKit/WebKit.h>

That's just a guess, though, since you haven't posted enough code to say for sure.